# Как разместить футер внизу страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Я понимаю что это не лучший вариант, так как такое намудрить мне пришлось в первые, это требование заказчика, код прикладываю, как поставить футер в низ в этом случае

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html,body{
 height:100%;
}
.clear{
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
.clear:after{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
.main{
 position:relative !important;
 /*height:100%;
 min-height:100%;*/
 background:green;
 /*overflow:hidden;
 overflow-y:auto;*/
}
.left{
 position:absolute;
 left:0; top:0;
 width:25%;
 min-height:300px;
 background:;
 z-index:98;
}
.center{
 position:absolute;
 left:25%; 
 top:0;
 right:0;
 width:50%;
 min-height:300px;
 background:;
 z-index:100;
 border-left:1px solid transparent;
 border-right:1px solid transparent;
}
.post{
 width:90%;
 margin:5px auto;
 min-height:200px;
 background:#fafafa;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-bottom:30px;
}
.post img{
 float:left;
 margin-left:4px;
 margin-top:4px;
 margin-right:10px;
 margin-bottom:4px;
 display:block;
 width:250px;
 height:150px;
 
}
.block{
 width:90%;
 margin:5px auto;
 min-height:200px;
 background:#fafafa; 
}
.widget{
 width:100%;
 min-height:330px;
 background:lightblue;
}
.widget img{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 
}
.block h2{
 padding-left:10px;
}
.block li{
 display:block;
 width:90%;
 margin:4px auto;
 height:27px;
 line-height:27px;
 padding-left:20px;
 position:relative;
}
.block li:hover:after{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:-3px; left:0;
 content:'';
 width:block;
 width:80%;
 height:5px;
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#fafaaf,#434343,#fefefe);
}
.block a{
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:16px;
}
.block form{
 text-transform:upercase;
}
.block  input{
 display:block;
 width:90%;
 height:30px;
 line-height:30px;
 margin:3px auto;
 font-size:12px;
}
.block  input[type=submit]{
 display:block;
 width:150px;
 height:20px;
 line-height:30px;
 margin:5px 13px;
}
.center p{
 width:90%;
 margin:20px auto;
 text-align:justify;
}
.right{
 position:absolute;
 left:75%; top:0;
 width:25%;
 min-height:300px;
 background:;
 z-index:97;
}
.header{
 min-height:200px;
}
.footer{
 height:200px;
 background:#c01;
    margin-top:30px;
 z-index:200;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main clear"> 
 <div class="center"> 
   <div class="post"> 
     <p><img src="" alt="" />
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem suscipit veniam, iure sit quis rerum ullam dolorum reiciendis necessitatibus, odio repellat mollitia, iste nesciunt. Laborum distinctio molestiae vitae facilis neque, quas placeat impedit totam in officia eaque, beatae quod! Officiis perspiciatis provident tempore dolor odio nulla cumque laudantium suscipit quaerat non! Repudiandae sint natus nulla. Aspernatur sint fuga, molestias repellat error perferendis, ea minus atque quo natus eum voluptate, maiores mollitia iusto nisi illum aliquam porro minima, quae ullam tempora! Dolorum distinctio perspiciatis facilis nesciunt ad similique dolorem, sapiente aspernatur quaerat modi animi provident, earum eligendi perferendis cumque facere magni eius temporibus nihil optio. Ab quae tempora ea reiciendis, optio itaque inventore voluptas quo consectetur, maiores veniam velit adipisci maxime perspiciatis numquam vitae minima iusto soluta! At, consequatur, voluptates. Error molestiae magnam dicta dolore soluta rerum optio delectus fugit nihil.
         </p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="post"> 
     <p><img src="" alt="" />
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem suscipit veniam, iure sit quis rerum ullam dolorum reiciendis necessitatibus, odio repellat mollitia, iste nesciunt. Laborum distinctio molestiae vitae facilis neque, quas placeat impedit totam in officia eaque, beatae quod! Officiis perspiciatis provident tempore dolor odio nulla cumque laudantium suscipit quaerat non! Repudiandae sint natus nulla. Aspernatur sint fuga, molestias repellat error perferendis, ea minus atque quo natus eum voluptate, maiores mollitia iusto nisi illum aliquam porro minima, quae ullam tempora! Dolorum distinctio perspiciatis facilis nesciunt ad similique dolorem, sapiente aspernatur quaerat modi animi provident, earum eligendi perferendis cumque facere magni eius temporibus nihil optio. Ab quae tempora ea reiciendis, optio itaque inventore voluptas quo consectetur, maiores veniam velit adipisci maxime perspiciatis numquam vitae minima iusto soluta! At, consequatur, voluptates. Error molestiae magnam dicta dolore soluta rerum optio delectus fugit nihil.
         </p>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="left"> 
  <div class="block"> 
     <!--Левый блок код поместить сюда-->
   
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
    <div class="block"> 
   <h2>Категории</h2>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Арт примеры</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Эротика</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Статьи</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PhotoShop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Css</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Php</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Продвинутый css</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Примеры</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Зарисовки</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div> 
  <div class="block"> 
    <!--Правый блок код поместить сюда-->
     <div class="widget"> 
    <img src="widget.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block"> 
     <form action="" name="" method="">
           ФОРМА АВТОРИЗАЦИИ  
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ"/>
    <input type="email" name="" placeholder="ЕMAIL ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ"/>
    <input type=""  name="" placeholder="ЛОГИН ПОЛЬЗОВАТЛЯ"/>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="ВОЙТИ"/>
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Футер `div.footer` окрашен в красный цвет, он находится после `div.main`. В блоке `div.main` три контейнера, которые абсолютно отпозиционированны внутри блока `div.main`, и из за этого такая каша. Помогите футер поставить в низ страницы.

Comment: держите на всякий случай костыль на JS http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrOvgZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот нужные изменения:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.main {
    /* ... */
    padding-bottom: 230px;
    /* 230 - это 200 высота футера + 30 верхний отступ (который из футера я убрал) */
}
.center {
    /* position:absolute; */
    /* центруйте этот блок как-то иначе. Вариантов
       немало, например в вашем случае может быть достаточно
       margin-left: 25%; */
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* margin-top:30px; - это не понадобится*/
    height: 200px;
}
```

Основная проблема `position:absolute;` у `div.center`. Из-за нее `div.main` имеет нулевую высоту и вы ничего с футером не сделаете, поскольку высота `div.center` меняется.

Приведенный вариант прижимает футер к низу страницы независимо от высоты контента (то есть если контента мало - футер все-равно будет внизу). Только основной фон надо вынести из `.main` в `body` и сделать фон для `.header`.

Answer (score 0):

если позиционировать .center с помощью релатив, то html страница будет видеть этот блок внутри блока .main, тогда блок .main будет иметь высоту равную высоте .center, а в вашей версии блок .main имеет высоту 0px, а footer располагается прямо под ним, как вы и хотите. То есть проблема только в высоте .main

`.center{
        position:relative;
        left:25%; 
        ...
    }`

Comment: И футер упадёт в низ ?

Comment: @LenovoID Ну вообще-то да. Интересно зачем минус человеку поставили?

Comment: Постарайтесь обосновывать ваши ответы, а не только постить код

Comment: Уже неплохо. Осталось теперь этот текст перенести в ответ (нажмите [edit]), а комментарий удалить. Также ознакомьтесь с [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Вашу задачу можно решить с помощью Flexbox

http://codepen.io/kuatmus/pen/PZjNvp

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html,body{
 display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}
.main{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: nowrap;
 position:relative;
 height:100%;
 min-height:100%;
 background:green;
 /*overflow:hidden;
 overflow-y:auto;*/
}
.left{
  width:25%;
  min-width: 250px;
 min-height:300px;
 background:;
 z-index:98;
}
.center{
  min-width: 460px;
 min-height:300px;
 background:;
 z-index:100;
 border-left:1px solid transparent;
 border-right:1px solid transparent;
}
.post{
 width:90%;
 margin:5px auto;
 min-height:200px;
 background:#fafafa;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-bottom:30px;
}
.post img{
 float:left;
 margin-left:4px;
 margin-top:4px;
 margin-right:10px;
 margin-bottom:4px;
 display:block;
 width:250px;
 height:150px;
 
}
.block{
 width:90%;
 margin:5px auto;
 min-height:200px;
 background:#fafafa; 
}
.widget{
 width:100%;
 min-height:330px;
 background:lightblue;
}
.widget img{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 
}
.block h2{
 padding-left:10px;
}
.block li{
 display:block;
 width:90%;
 margin:4px auto;
 height:27px;
 line-height:27px;
 padding-left:20px;
 position:relative;
}
.block li:hover:after{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:-3px; left:0;
 content:'';
 width:block;
 width:80%;
 height:5px;
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#fafaaf,#434343,#fefefe);
}
.block a{
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:16px;
}
.block form{
 text-transform:upercase;
}
.block  input{
 display:block;
 width:90%;
 height:30px;
 line-height:30px;
 margin:3px auto;
 font-size:12px;
}
.block  input[type=submit]{
 display:block;
 width:150px;
 height:20px;
 line-height:30px;
 margin:5px 13px;
}
.center p{
 width:90%;
 margin:20px auto;
 text-align:justify;
}
.right{
 width:25%;
  min-width: 250px;
 min-height:300px;
 background:;
 z-index:97;
}
.header{
 min-height:200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.footer{
 height:200px;
 background:#c01;
 z-index:200;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="block">
        <!--Левый блок код поместить сюда-->

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="post">
        <p><img src="" alt="" /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem suscipit veniam, iure sit quis rerum ullam dolorum reiciendis necessitatibus, odio repellat mollitia, iste nesciunt. Laborum distinctio molestiae vitae facilis
          neque, quas placeat impedit totam in officia eaque, beatae quod! Officiis perspiciatis provident tempore dolor odio nulla cumque laudantium suscipit quaerat non! Repudiandae sint natus nulla. Aspernatur sint fuga, molestias repellat error perferendis,
          ea minus atque quo natus eum voluptate, maiores mollitia iusto nisi illum aliquam porro minima, quae ullam tempora! Dolorum distinctio perspiciatis facilis nesciunt ad similique dolorem, sapiente aspernatur quaerat modi animi provident, earum
          eligendi perferendis cumque facere magni eius temporibus nihil optio. Ab quae tempora ea reiciendis, optio itaque inventore voluptas quo consectetur, maiores veniam velit adipisci maxime perspiciatis numquam vitae minima iusto soluta! At, consequatur,
          voluptates. Error molestiae magnam dicta dolore soluta rerum optio delectus fugit nihil.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="post">
        <p><img src="" alt="" /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem suscipit veniam, iure sit quis rerum ullam dolorum reiciendis necessitatibus, odio repellat mollitia, iste nesciunt. Laborum distinctio molestiae vitae facilis
          neque, quas placeat impedit totam in officia eaque, beatae quod! Officiis perspiciatis provident tempore dolor odio nulla cumque laudantium suscipit quaerat non! Repudiandae sint natus nulla. Aspernatur sint fuga, molestias repellat error perferendis,
          ea minus atque quo natus eum voluptate, maiores mollitia iusto nisi illum aliquam porro minima, quae ullam tempora! Dolorum distinctio perspiciatis facilis nesciunt ad similique dolorem, sapiente aspernatur quaerat modi animi provident, earum
          eligendi perferendis cumque facere magni eius temporibus nihil optio. Ab quae tempora ea reiciendis, optio itaque inventore voluptas quo consectetur, maiores veniam velit adipisci maxime perspiciatis numquam vitae minima iusto soluta! At, consequatur,
          voluptates. Error molestiae magnam dicta dolore soluta rerum optio delectus fugit nihil.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="block">
        <h2>Категории</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Арт примеры</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Эротика</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Статьи</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PhotoShop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Css</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Php</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Продвинутый css</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Примеры</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Зарисовки</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <!--Правый блок код поместить сюда-->
        <div class="widget">
          <img src="widget.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <form action="" name="" method="">
          ФОРМА АВТОРИЗАЦИИ
          <input type="text" name="" placeholder="ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ" />
          <input type="email" name="" placeholder="ЕMAIL ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ" />
          <input type="" name="" placeholder="ЛОГИН ПОЛЬЗОВАТЛЯ" />
          <input type="submit" name="" value="ВОЙТИ" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"> </div>
```

body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }

main { flex: 1 0 auto; }

Подробнее про Flexbox:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Можно в качестве шаблона использовать отрицательный margin у обертки контента, тогда футер будет прижат независимо от контента основных блоков вот пример такого шаблона:

```css
html{
 height:100%;
}
body{
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
}
#content{
 width: 800px;
 min-height: 100%;
 background: #66ccff;
 margin:0 auto -150px;
}
#footer{
 width: 800px;
 height: 150px;
 background: #66cc00;
 margin:auto;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
```

Если необходимы правые и левые колонки то можно поступить следующим образом:

```css
html{
 height:100%;
}
body{
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
}
#content{
 width: 800px;
 min-height: 100%;
 background: #66ccff;
 margin:0 auto -150px;
}
#footer{
 width: 800px;
 height: 150px;
 background: #66cc00;
 margin:auto;
 clear:both;
}
.left{
 width:200px;
 float:left;
 outline:1px solid #9F00BF;
}
.right{
 width:200px;
 float:right;
 outline:1px solid #9F00BF;
}
.center{
 margin:0 210px;
 outline:1px solid #9F00BF;
}
.limiter{
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="right">text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text</div>
  <div class="left">text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text</div>
  <div class="center">text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text</div>
  <div class="limiter"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
```